# Calculating double integral by converting to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^1\int_x^1 \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \ dy\,dx $$

**My attempt:**

So I've converted the integral into polar coordinates, getting the integral

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)} \theta r\,dr\,d\theta \ =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\theta }{2\cos^2(\theta)} \, d\theta \ $$

However I have no idea where to go from here? Have I calculated the limits wrong or am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Ok, in order to integrate the $\theta$ function, go for integration by parts, choose $f=\theta$ and $g'=csc^2\theta$

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that! Thank you for guiding me!

Comment: Are there any easier ways to achieve this answer?

Comment: hmmm, I thought my approach was kind of easy, in the sense that behind the integral sign you get a $cot\theta$ and that has a standard anti derivative in the form of $ln|sin\theta|$

Comment: Looking at the integral again I believe I have made a mistake and it should be $\cos(\theta)$ not $\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Doesn't matter much for the approach. Still use integration by parts. Now take $g'=sec^2\theta$ which has an anti derivative of $tan\theta$ and that anti deriving ultimately becomes an $ln|cos\theta|$

Comment: Could you please check for me if I have calculated the limits correctly?

Comment: Do you have your limits of integration correct?

Comment: The limits of $y$ should be from $x$ to $1$?

Comment: I just noticed that you have $\displaystyle \int_1^x$ rather than $\displaystyle\int_0^x$.  That would change some things, although the general method is still the general method. $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry, My mistake! Wrote the question wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\theta} \theta r\,dr\,d\theta.
$$
Notice that $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.  So you have a right triangle whose "adjacent" side has length $1$, and $r$ is the length of the hypotenuse.
$$
\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \cos\theta = \frac 1 r,
$$
so $r$ goes up to $1/\cos\theta$.  So you get
\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac \theta {2\cos^2\theta} \,d\theta = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \theta \Big( \sec^2\theta \,d\theta \Big) \\[12pt]
= {} & \overbrace{\frac 1 2 \int \theta\,dv = \frac 1 2 \theta v - \frac 1 2 \int v\,d\theta}^\text{integration by parts} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \left[ \theta\tan\theta \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]_0^{\pi/4} - \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan\theta\,d\theta = \text{etc.}
\end{align}
Recall that
\begin{align}
& \int\tan\theta\,d\theta = \int \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta \\[6pt]
= {} & \int \frac {-1}{\cos\theta} \Big( - \sin\theta\,d\theta\Big) = \int \frac {-1} u\,du = \text{etc.}
\end{align}

Comment: ok, You have $\displaystyle \int_x^1$ rather than $\displaystyle \int_0^x$.  So $\theta$ would need to go from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

Do you have your limits of integration correct?

In Cartesian, if your limits are set up correctly at the beginning, your region is 
$x=y, y=1, x=0$  And since $x<1$ you are going to get a negative value when you integrate.

After you have converted, you have $r = \csc \theta$ which is consistent with y=1.  If the rest of the set up was right, you should have $\theta$ from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$

Alternatively, if your region was $x = 1, y=0, x=y$ your limit become $r$ from $0$ to $\sec\theta, \theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/4$

Comment: Wait why is r cscθ instead of √2 ?

Comment: In x=y, y=1, x=0 and x<=1 , the greatest distance from origin is √2 right?

Comment: You are commenting on a question that is 3 years old.  Anyway, when we convert to polar, the line $y=1$ becomes $r\sin\theta = 1 \implies r = \csc\theta$

Comment: But r is distance from origin  and greatest distance in this region is between 0 and (1, 1) ? Our region is  a right angle triangle with r as hypotenuse

Comment: The coordinates are (0, 0), (0, 1) and(1, 1) and greatest distance of r is 0 to (1, 1) ie √2 .

Comment: When $\theta = \frac {pi}{4}, r$ can be as large as $\sqrt 2$  but when $\theta = \frac {pi}{2}, r$ must be less than or equal to $1.$  The range of $r$ depends on $\theta$

Comment: Ah okay. That's what I was messing up! Thanks a lot